# Buttons not responding when I set <httpCookies httpOnlyCookies=“true” requireSSL=“true” />

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, cookies, session-cookies

To secure my cookie attributes, I am using the below code in Web.config.

```
<httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" requireSSL="true" />
```

But after applying the changes, most of the buttons in my Web application is not responding. How to resolve the issue?

I have tried using developer tool. Below is the error I am getting using the developer tool

> Uncaught Error: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that  configuration specifies the same validationKey and validation algorithm. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster.

Comment: Delete your cookies and try again.  The existing cookies do not use SSL which will confuse the server.  The buttons that are not working are using existing cookies that do not contain the SSL and have not expired.  Removing the existing cookies should get buttons working unless the server the button are using do not accept SSL.

Comment: How can I delete the cookies?

Comment: I have tried deleting cookies from browser and tried. No change in the result. The buttons are not yet responding

Comment: Do you get error with/without developer tool? Does error occur before or after pushing button?  Do you have exception handlers (try/catch) in code?  Can you isolate what instruction is causing error?

Comment: I am getting error with the developer tool only. Without that the buttons are not responding.
All the button clicks which are not responding throws this error in developer tool
I use exception handlers in the code. This error occurs after pushing the button

Comment: I would not use developer tool which will be harder to fix issue.  I would use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler to help isolate issue.  There is a good article at codeproject that I often recommend for SSL : https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1000189/A-Working-TCP-Client-and-Server-With-SSL